# Google Calendar not appearing in gnome-calendar

Tags: gnome, 16.04, google, calendar, online-accounts

I just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 and also upgraded GNOME to 3.20 and my Google calendar isn't showing events & isn't listed in settings either.

The Google account is set up correctly in Online Accounts and everything else integrates properly (documents, photos, contacts, files etc).

This screenshot shows Calendar telling me there isn't a Google account (click to set up) but having clicked you can see that the account is already there...

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Simply logging out and in again solved the problem for me :)

Comment: that did the trick for me too

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar not working with the GNOME Calendar 3.20 app is a bug with the GNOME3 Staging PPA, as reported by [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-gnome-320-in-ubuntu.html).

If you want to use a more stable version of GNOME with probably fewer bugs, do not use the GNOME3 Staging PPA.

Comment: I have a very similar problem and I'm not using any PPA. The only difference is that I'm not even asked to add the Google account at all. It is configured correctly under Online Accounts, but still nothing!

Comment: What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

search for "Private Address" on google agenda detail of your calendar and copy the link, than click on ADD on the ubuntu calendar and paste the click from google agenda. And job done.