# Can't sync Google Calendar with GNOME Calendar

Tags: 16.04

How can I set up sync between Google and GNOME Calendar? I did some research and most examples show the setup through the GNOME Online Accounts. It looks straightforward, but my issue is after I've setup my Google Account with GNOME Online Account, I only see possible sync in applications I don't care about. Essentially I would like to sync Nautilus with Google Drive and Calendar.

Anyone knows why I'm only seeing a subset?

GNOME Calendar is installed on my machine. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image]

Comment: What isn't syncing with the calendar? You should see your calendar in GNOME calendar with _Evolution Data Server_ access enabled.

Comment: Doing this will mess up Chromium.  You will end up removing this account to make it work again with sync.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Calendar, Maya, and many other Gtk+ [calendars use Evolution data server](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/gnome-caldav) as their backend. If you first install Evolution, then you can  use it to [configure your CalDAV calendars](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/calendar-caldav.html.en) (such as iCloud, Yahoo!, and Google) and other accounts.

It’s very unfortunate that neither Ubuntu Online Accounts nor GNMOE Online Accounts expose standard protocols such as CalDAV and CardDAV and rather choose to focus on some partner service providers such as Google.

Comment: I resorted in installing Evolution, it sync fine now in evolution calendar and the Gnome calendar. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It worked for me. For some reason my calender stopped syncing and i installed evolution app from Ubuntu software center and that sorted out problem Now everything works fine. Revanth B

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/779343/4918 just relogging works, no need for Evolution!

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I resorted in installing Evolution and set up the sync through evolution. It syncs fine now in evolution calendar and I can also see my events directly in the Gnome calendar. I found it a bit odd to have to install a main client to set up a calendar sync, but it does the job.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/779343/4918 just relogging works, no need for Evolution!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is still the case.

By default, on a new 17.10 installation, both the GNOME Calendar and Contacts apps only look to save things locally.  It's a real pain, because they continue to do that even after you set up your online accounts under settings.  They do not default to the new Google Calendar/Contacts (for example) or even ask if you would like the new Google account to be the default for all contacts and calendar management.

I had to install Evolution and configure things in there.  Not ideal, given I use Thunderbird for e-mails (IMAP).

Worth also noting that it seems impossible to use outlook.com calendars or contacts at all.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue in my experience with this problem is that Google was blocking a 'less secure app' and I had to manually go in and change setting in my Google account to allow Evolution access to the account.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one. Look on the left. There are a number of events, groups, and calendars to choose from. If you are on yourname@google.com and that is the calendar you want to sync to, it will work. If you have another calendar highlighted, you will receive and error.

I found a column on the left in Evolution with a list of accounts for the calendar. I had something checked, changed it to the Google email address and everything was fine. Except for the fact when I add or update an appointment, a popup tells me it could not be updated, but when I close that down without saving, the new or changed appointment shows up on my phone with the calendar.

Comment: Can you please explain further? "Look on the left" of what?